# android приложение с базой данных

Tags: java, android, база-данных, сервер

До этого делал лишь клиентские android приложения, просто никакие данные хранить не требовалось. Теперь возникает вопрос. У меня есть приложение, там авторизация пользователя и у при входе у каждого свой всплывающий список из данных. База данных имеется. Вопрос как ее прикрепить к этому android приложению. Еще нужно что бы например 2 человека скачали приложение, один зарегался, а второй потом сможет зайти с этими данными. Как это реализовать?

Comment: т.е. база должна быть не локальной на каждом устройстве, а одна общая?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, Вам, стоити посмотреть в сторону [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/). Вот хороший [гайд](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/10/android-working-with-firebase-realtime-database/), который может, Вам, помочь